# How to just pick first while cloning in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
$('.cloneMe').on('click', function(e) {
    var idToAppend = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).data('id', idToAppend + 1);
    $('div.render-form-editlayout-10').clone("").find('[id]').attr('id', function(idx, val) {
        var newId = (this.name == undefined) ? val + idToAppend : this.name + '_' + idToAppend;
        if ((this.name != undefined)) {
          $(this).attr('name', newId);
          console.log('For elements with name the new ID is: ' +
                newId + ' new Name is: ' + newId);
        }
        return newId;
    }).closest('div.render-form-editlayout-10').insertBefore(this);
})
```

And my jsfiddle is **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/56sfx5ur/16/)**

When you click on the plus button it works fine for the first time, But next time it's cloning more than one, How Can I fix it without changing other logic?

Thanks

Comment: for me it clones 1 every time I press '+'.

Comment: What does all this data-id mean? I fixed your wrong cloning in the previous fiddle but before I could submit my answer you changed it to the new one.

Comment: @hallleron it was a wrong fiddle sory I updated

Comment: @hallleron actually the class if you see `render-form-editlayout-10` it has the same last digit as `data-id` of the button

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line : `$('div.render-form-editlayout-10').clone("")`.

if you want to pick the first, use the [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) method: `$('div.render-form-editlayout-10').first().clone("")`

I updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/56sfx5ur/12/). But the problem in your jsfiddle was the used selector. I fixed it too. Your fiddle differ from your given code so i can't say if your original code has the same problem.

Comment: what if i have to clone all the rows other than the f-row first , The heading is also getting cloned as well , Also I am trying to make the class dynamic , for example `render-form-editlayout-10` this could be changed to data-id of the button

Comment: I Updated my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56sfx5ur/15/

I update the following js line:

```
 var new_form = $('.form-model').children().first().clone(true);
```

The problem was that you cloned the whole container which at first contained only one set of form fields but on the second clone it contained 2 form field set so a clone yielded 4 form sets, etc..

Comment: sorry I updated the wrong fiddle , now can you please check